# Fixed/not re-sizable cropping window

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        //indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("scale", false);
        cropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", false);
        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

Nothing comes out with my search. Forgive me if there is a duplicate somewhere out there.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Hld.png)

I want the cropping window not to be resize. just fixed.

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent` action](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). Your code will fail on a lot of Android devices. There are plenty of [image-cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks! Can you please recommend a tutorial something that can do circular crop

Comment: You will need to see which of those libraries off circular cropping, or find some other library. For example, when I typed `android circular crop library` into DuckDuckGo, I turned up [this](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper), which appears to offer circular cropping as an option.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks dude! I found CropIwa and it is good. However, I am a newbie and its hard to understand the documentation. Anyways, Thank you once again. Such a good person. Spread Love.